# Using Java swing GUI with logic in another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, logic, connect

I would like to use a swing GUI from another class where I have logic for my program.
Logic class is class ApsVaje1 in the code below. 
For example I have two classes GUI and Logic. In GUI I have JTextArea and JTextField and a JButton. In the class logic I have methods which do some operations and in main method of the logic class I do like

## Pseudocode

when buttun clicked:

```
String text = GUI.JTextField.get text    
String result = Method1(text)    
JText Area.setText(result)
```

## My code:

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form GUI
     */
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Vnesi");

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 286, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 14, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 277, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 149, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
    public  String getField1Text(){
         return this.jTextField1.getText();
    }

    public  void setAreaText(String text){
        this.jTextArea1.setText(text);
    }

}
```

and

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ApsVaje1 {

    Sportnik[] tabelaSportnikov = new Sportnik[0];
    int vnos = 0;
    String podatki = "";
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public Sportnik[] tvoriSportnike(int n){
        Sportnik[] tabelaSportnikov = new Sportnik[n];
        return tabelaSportnikov;
    }

    public  void izpisiTabelo(){
        for(int i = 0; i< tabelaSportnikov.length; i++){
            System.out.println(tabelaSportnikov[i].toString());

        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI.main(args);
        while (true){            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: what you are looking for is a [actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). Have your `Logic` class implement the interface, then register the class as a listener to your button.

Comment: You're doing it backwards. The GUI class should be the main class, and should instantiate the logic class and call its methods. The logic class shouldn't care about the GUI.

Comment: Btw, learn Java naming conventions and stick to them. Your current code is really hard to read for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not clear.
But as far as I understand, 
Just create the instance of GUI  in the class ApsVaje1. After that you can use any logic of ApsVaje1  on GUI. The main method of GUI can be removed.

I hope it works for you problem. If you think, I didn't understand the question, then please clarify the question again.